# Logic: Is $\exists n\in\Bbb{Z}^+,\forall m\in\Bbb{Z}^+,m\leq n$ True or False?

Tags: logic

I think it's false because if $n=0$, then the statement does not hold for all positive integer $m$. But I'm not sure the answer.
Please let me know if i'm wrong.

Comment: The statement asks if there exists an $n$ such that for all $m....$

Comment: Do you understand what $\exists$ and $\forall$ mean?

Comment: @BIN, this question has 3 answers and you have neither accepted any of them nor pointed out where you are still confused. This is a reminder that if an answer answers your question, please upvote it and click the checkmark under the arrows to accept it as the best answer. First, this helps other users with the same problem quickly identify the best answer to read and second this is also a form of saying thanks to the answerer.

Answer (score 1):

So this is related to an important question: how do we prove that something is false? For this statement, if it were true, then there would be some special $n$ with this property. To prove this, it would be enough to present this $n$ and show the property holds.

However, to prove this *false* it is not enough to present an $n$ and show that the statement doesn’t hold, which is what you did. What if you just picked the wrong $n$? What if there’s some other special $n$ which works and you just didn’t find it?

To make it clear, let’s explicitly consider the *negation* of our statement, and try to prove that true. $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$:
$$\neg (\exists n \; \forall m \; m\leq n)$$
$$\iff$$
$$\forall n \; \exists m \; m> n $$

Now it is clear. Because the existential quantifier is *after* the universal, we may choose $m$ *as a function of n*. So of course, $m=n+1$ works. Now since we have proved the negation true, the original statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion is right. However, let's check the thought process. To put the statement in a plain text, it says whether there exists a positive integer such that every positive integer is smaller than or equal to it. Clearly it is wrong.

**But why?**

Because for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}+$, if we let $m=n+1\in\mathbb{Z}+$, then $m\leq n$ does not hold. The proof is finished.

You can see that it is different from your proof. We cannot only say for a certain $n$(in your case, you only consider $n=0$), the statement $\forall m, m\leq n$ fails.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb Z^+$ excludes $0$, so any allusion to it in an argument is irrelevant.  You need to find a positive integer to substitute in for $n$.  For example,

$$\forall m \in \Bbb Z^+ ~:~m \le  7$$

Well that's not true.  But you need to either find an integer other than $7$ that makes it true or argue that no such integer exists.